# What can I do to attract expert users?

Tags: discussion, users

Artificial intelligence is developing at rapid level and there are several experts around the world. Coming to academics, there are large number of professors available compared to last decade. Artificial intelligence also became a compulsory course in developing countries.

Although I asked some questions on [Data Sciences](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/47826/hanugm?tab=questions) and [Cross Validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/42883/hanugm?tab=questions) stack exchange sites. I *personally* feel that our main site is less in no way and I can opine that our main site has better chances to contribute in a better way than other sites. I feel that our site is mostly visited by the beginners or intermediates like me.
Beginners generally tend to ask more and more questions.

So, there is a great need to increase in the critical mass of the experts. Else, in long run, beginners may feel either hopeless or neglected. It may in turn decline our site progress.

In order to not make it happen, along with the efforts to make the experts on our main site active, we need to attract the new expert users that are either unaware about our site or contributing on other sites etc.,

What kind of activities I(any one) can do in order to attract the new experts to our main site?

Comment: Might it be helpful to kinda have programming questions about AI also included in the AI .stackexchange? In the hope to attract people that try to implement papers, what in-turn might attract experts that might have written the papers or tried implementing it themselves.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with your points. This is a question that I've been asking myself for a long time, but I don't have a definitive answer/solution. Some potential solutions are

1. Advertise our website (but not sure how and where); I've tried to do this sporadically and not very seriously (e.g. by pasting links on other chats, but this actually led to some hot debates between me and others, so I've stopped doing this)
2. Talk about this site to your friends/colleagues/classmates (when you have the occasion)
3. Mention the name of this site in events like conferences or workshops

We should highlight the strengths of our site and we should especially try to attract users that are interested in those strengths and topics. We tend to attract several users interested in reinforcement learning (which is very nice, given that RL is very central to AI), but, unfortunately, we do not attract many qualified users in other areas, like the philosophy of AI, cognitive architectures, AGI, evolutionary computation or even just the regular machine learning topics.

Comment: as an example days ago I was trying to answer the contributions in AGI of Russia. They have one project related to that in a paper from 2012 I contact the founder through linkedin because the website is offline and if the project is still open and he answer:>No, this project is inactive now. We joined SingularityNET.and I respond him >I was trying to answer this [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/4112/is-russia-contributing-to-open-research-concerning-friendly-ai) I think this is a good way to attract expert users to AI.SE finding interest in the question and answer of this site

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the time/focus/energy to do this, but, if I did, I would spam social media sites with the best Q&As.

It's blows my mind, but people actually got to places like Quora and reddit for information.  I'm not saying you can't occasionally finds pearls hidden under all the garbage, but it's rarely worth the effort.

Users on other stacks used to claim we had no function, and should be subsumed into overlapping stack.  We disagreed.  **Strongly.**

Our scope, even narrowed, is still one of the widest—our field overlaps pretty much every field in some way.  The related stacks could never deal with this potential depth.

We can take questions on the social impacts and history and etymology, in addition to the mathematical treatment of AI theory.  We can discuss the philosophy, not just the practice.

Can you talk about Searle or Minsky and their ideas on those other stack? Can you ask what was the first AI?  Or about what AI means? Nope.